# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS packages

Tags: ros, package, build-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

ROS provides open source packages for installation and those packages are found in "opt/ros/noetic/share" folder assuming noetic is the distro.

I might be confusing things but are there any packages that are being installed in catkin_ws/src folder? Or is it just packages created by us?

I am searching /reading around for awhile now and started on building a ROS LiDAR mobile robot with navigation stack + gmapping.

Can I confirm that after URDF is written with other parameters set (diff drive controller etc), I just have to create a package in "catkin_ws/src/launch" folder with a launch file launching the necessary packages (packages which is located "opt/ros/noetic/share")?

Thank you all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396251/ros-packages/) by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2022-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @1024son,

Please take a look at [prior answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/196283/catkin_ws-vs-share/) explains the difference between `/opt/ros/..` and `catkin_ws`

To your question:

> Can I confirm that after URDF is
> written with other parameters set
> (diff drive controller etc), I just
> have to create a package in
> "catkin_ws/src/launch" folder with a
> launch file launching the necessary
> packages (packages which is located
> "opt/ros/noetic/share")?

Yes. If you use `catkin_make` for example is a convenience tool for building code in a catkin workspace.
Refer to the following documentation for more information why `catkin` was created and the different tools that can be used:

[Catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin)

[REP-0128](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0128.html)

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-02-21**:
Thank you.It seems that my previous search before posting were not worded to have answers I'm seeking.
That link explains well.
Thanks again.